# Axis connection types

Tags: motors, coupling

Complete hobbyist here. I have two questions I have a problem figuring out.
I have hard time finding information about axis and types of connections they have. For example take this worm gear reducer:

[image]

It has axis connection with small extrusion on one side, where motors usually have shaft with one flat side. I found this adapter :

[image]

on the site it's called `Axle sleeve` but I haven't found this part by this name elsewhere, so maybe there is another more precise term?

Is there a beginner friendly resource I can study to get more familiar with this system? What both types of connections are called etc.

Comment: Your misconception is that "motors usually have a shaft with one flat side". This is not the case. Motors of the size designed for use with a gearbox like that usually have a plain shaft that can be post-machined, or with a slot. Shafts with flats are typically used on smaller, lighter duty motors.

Comment: OK, thank you. Could you tell me the name of this connection?

Comment: You’re looking at a Keyway - the shaft needs to have a Key. There are several types of Key with different benefits https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_(engineering)